# barplots in R comparing data from two columns

Tags: r

I have the following:

```
> ArkHouse2014 <-  read.csv(file="C:/Rwork/ar14.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
> ArkHouse2014
DISTRICT   GOP   DEM
1     AR-60 3,951 4,001
2     AR-61 3,899 4,634
3     AR-62 5,130 4,319
4    AR-100 6,550 3,850
5     AR-52 5,425 3,019
6     AR-10 3,638 5,009
7     AR-32 6,980 5,349
```

What I would like to do is make a barplot (or series of barplots) to compare the totals in the second and third columns on the y-axis while the x-axis would display the information in the first column.

It seems like this should be very easy to do, but most of the information on making barplots that I can find has you make a table from the data and then barplot that, e.g.,

```
> table(ArkHouse2014$GOP)

2,936 3,258 3,508 3,573 3,581 3,588 3,638 3,830 3,899 3,951 4,133 4,166 4,319 4,330 4,345 4,391 4,396 4,588 
    1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1        1     1     1     1     1     1 
4,969 5,130 5,177 5,343 5,425 5,466 5,710 5,991 6,070 6,100 6,234 6,490 6,550 6,980 7,847 8,846 
1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

I don't want the counts of how many have each total, I'd like to just represent the quantities visually. I feel pretty stupid not being able to figure this out, so thanks in advance for any advice you have to offer me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option using libraries `reshape2` and `ggplot2`:

I first read your data (with `dec = ","`):

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="DISTRICT   GOP   DEM
                 1     AR-60 3,951 4,001
                 2     AR-61 3,899 4,634
                 3     AR-62 5,130 4,319
                 4    AR-100 6,550 3,850
                 5     AR-52 5,425 3,019
                 6     AR-10 3,638 5,009
                 7     AR-32 6,980 5,349", dec = ",")
```

Then reshape it to long format:

```
library(reshape2)
df_long <- melt(df, id.var = "DISTRICT")
```

Then create a barplot using `ggplot`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df_long, aes(x = DISTRICT, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

[image: pic]

or if you want the bars stacked:

```
ggplot(df_long, aes(x = DISTRICT, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```